# Haskell Function on tuple list how to compare all component with each following component

Tags: list, haskell, data-structures, tuples

I am trying to create a func that compares a element from a tuple list with every other List for a special datatype:

```
data Term = Var VarName | Comb CombName [Term]
  deriving (Eq, Show)
data Subst = Subst [(VarName, Term)]
  deriving Show
```

So I am trying to do the following:

```
[(VarName "Y",Comb "2" []),(VarName "Y",Var (VarName "X"))]   -> Subst [(VarName "Y",Comb "2" [])]
```

If we have a tuple (a,b) then we wanna check every tuple from [(VarName,Term)]
if there is any tuple (c,d) where a=b if yes then we wanna check if b has type Comb x [] or d has type Comb x []. After checking that we wanna delete the tuple, which second component hasnt the type Comb x []. (It isnt possible that there are to tuples who have both Comb x [] as type as second component)

My try:

```
test :: [(VarName,Term)] -> [(VarName,Term)]
test []         = []
test ((x,y):[]) = ((x,y):[]) 
test ((x,y):xs) = map (check (x,y) xs)

check (VarName,Term) -> [(VarName,Term)] -> (VarName,Term)
check (x,y) [] = [(x,y)]
check (x,y) ((a,b):xs) = if x==a && y = CombName i [] then (x,y) else ((a,b))
```

Can some1 please help me out, I am new with Haskell. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish at a higher level perhaps? Or maybe provide more input/output examples.

Comment: I am trying to build a compiler for Prolog++ like relations on haskell and I need to get rid of the double occurences. Another example:
[(VarName "X",Var (VarName "Y")),(VarName "X",Comb "true" []))]   -> Subst [(VarName "X",Comb "true" [])]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `nubBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`. Try `nubBy (on (==) fst)`.